# InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host error

Tags: python, powershell, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, urllib3

I have installed Google Cloud CLI on my windows computer and When i am running the gcloud command from my windows computer through PowerShell I am getting below error message;

```
python.exe : C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1063: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 
'iam.googleapis.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
At C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud.ps1:114 char:3
+   & "$cloudsdk_python" $run_args_array
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\Program File...ml#ssl-warnings:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I read in many posts that we can disable this error message by adding this below lines

import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

Or

import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

But I am not sure on which file and path i need to add above lines. I tried to add that lines on file “C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\urllib3\connectionpool.py” by editing it in notepad and saved it but still i am getting the same error. Can someone please guide me how to stop this error from the PowerShell script.

Regards.

Comment: The error is occurring because you TLS certificate is not signed.  It may be a proxy (see : https://discuss.python.org/t/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-self-signed-certificate/14359).  Did you try ssl_verify=False (see https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/issues/240).  The following article has good explanation of the issue : https://www.clickssl.net/blog/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-in-python

Comment: what gcloud command did you run which resulted in that error being displayed?

Comment: I do not know the solution but do not apply bandaids to cover up the warning messages. There is something wrong with your system's setup. Find and fix that instead.

Comment: I have already read it many suggestions that i need to user below lines to fix this error;


import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings() 

but no body mentions clearly where to use above lines. Is this a command to execute or the lines we need to append on any of the files on path “C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\urllib3\connectionpool.py” or on any other files?

Comment: Let me repeat. Do not mask SSL security warnings unless you like your data stolen or your system hacked. And I hope nobody helps you mask those warnings with the Google Cloud SDK.